# python parsing xml in one particular pattern

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a xml file in such format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TAGA>
   <TAGB>TEXTB</TAGB>
   TEXTA
</TAGA>
```

I am using `elementTree` in parse this part of the file.

I can successfully get the "TEXTB" out, by using `TagB.text`.

My problem is with "TEXTA".  I have tried  `TagA.text`, which always returned `None`.  Does anyone have any idea how I should get the "TEXTA" out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [***tail***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) attribute of [***xml.etree.ElementTree.Element***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) object:

In this case, `tail` attribute will hold the text between the `TAGB` end tag and the next tag

```
...
tree = ET.parse("yourfile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

print(root.find('TAGB').tail.strip())
```

The output:

```
TEXTA
```